# Injective Map and Inequalities

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory

"Define $ϕ:A→B×C,\ g(H∩K)↦(gH,gK)$.

Note that $ϕ$ is well defined and also it's trivial that it is injective.

Thus, $|A|≤|B||C|$."

is from the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985456/how-do-i-prove-gh-cap-k-leq-ghgk?rq=1).

But my question is, why does the inequality follow from the fact that the map is injective? I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the definitions of cardinality is that $ |A| \leq |B| $ is equivalent to the existence of an injective mapping $ A \to B$.  So inequality follows directly from the definition of cardinality.